# how do i wait for the task in GULP4 SERIES

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an error "Could not find file SVG" in the task 'svg:inject'.

So what's happens: the task 'svg:sprite' generates file sprite.svg. Then in the task 'svg:inject' I want to use this sprite.svg to move it in html.
But I have an error ((

Have you any ideas about this behavior and about solving it?

```
gulp.task('svg:sprite', (done) => {
    gulp.src('./resources/svg/sprite/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgstore())
        .pipe(dest('./resources/svg/'));
    done();
});

gulp.task('svg:inject', gulp.series('svg:sprite', (done) => {
    gulp.src('./resources/svg/sprite-svg.html')
        .pipe(injectSvg({
            base: './resources/svg/'
        }))
        .pipe(dest('./resources/_code/templates/'));
    done();
}));
```

sprite-svg.html file:

```
<div class="hide">
    <img src="sprite.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the stream instead of using the `done` callback:

```js
gulp.task('svg:sprite', () =>
  gulp.src('./resources/svg/sprite/*.svg')
    .pipe(svgstore())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/svg/'))
);

gulp.task('svg:inject', gulp.series('svg:sprite', () =>
  gulp.src('./resources/svg/sprite-svg.html')
    .pipe(injectSvg({
        base: './resources/svg/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/_code/templates/'))
));
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have one more question above. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

**TheDancingCode** thanks! It helps.

But one question: I try to use require for tasks. And in this case, I get an error message:

> The following tasks did not complete: svg:inject, svg:sprite 
>   Did you forget to signal async completion?

What is wrong?

Code:

```
function getTask(task, path_src, path_dest) {
    return require('./tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins, path_src, path_dest);
};

gulp.task('svg:sprite', () => {
    getTask('svg-sprite', CONFIG.src.svg_sprite, CONFIG.src.svg)
});

gulp.task('svg:inject', gulp.series('svg:sprite', () => {
    getTask('svg-inject', CONFIG.src.svg, CONFIG.src.html_templates)
}));
```

And an example of a task module (svg-sprite.js):

```
module.exports = function (gulp, plugins, path_src, path_dest) {
    gulp.src(path_src)
        .pipe(plugins.svgstore())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path_dest));
};
```

Comment: Once again, add `return` statements before `getTask` and `gulp.src`.

Comment: Thank you. It helps.
Why did 'return' statement solve a problem?